# AngleSharp вставить данные в input

Tags: c#, html, парсер, anglesharp

Использую библиотеку AngleSharp, успешно нашел нужные мне input через селектор тэг/имя класса. Дальше вопрос, каким образом подставить данные в input?

```
foreach (IElement element in document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("input.bginput"))
{

}
```

```html
<table class="tborder" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="800px" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="tcat">����</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="panelsurround">
      <div class="panel">
        <div align="left">

          <script type="text/javascript" src="/cyberstatic.net/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=389"></script>
          <form action="login.php?do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, )">
            <input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" />
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="/log-in.php" />
            <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />
            <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" />


            <input type="hidden" name="s" value="e721bb0d17d8a4690e134a57e8d7b35f" />
            <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="guest" />

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td>E-mail:<br /><input type="text" class="bginput" name="vb_login_username" size="50" accesskey="u" tabindex="1" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>������:<br /><input type="password" class="bginput" name="vb_login_password" size="50" tabindex="1" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="smallfont" style="float:right"><a href="login.php?do=lostpw">������������ ������</a></span>
                  <span class="smallfont" style="float:right; margin-right: 10px"><a href="register.php">�����������</a></span>
                  <label for="cb_cookieuser" class="smallfont"><input type="checkbox" name="cookieuser" value="1" id="cb_cookieuser" tabindex="1" checked="checked" />���������?</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right">
                  <input type="submit" class="button" value="����" accesskey="s" tabindex="1" />
                  <input type="reset" class="button" value="�����" accesskey="r" tabindex="1" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>


          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Пробовали установить Value для инпута?

Comment: Я думал об этом, но не знаю как это сделать в коде. Документация плохая у этой библиотеки, искал подобные примеры в интернете, не нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `.SetAttribute`:

```
foreach (IElement element in document.Body.QuerySelectorAll("input.bginput"))
{
    element.SetAttribute("value", "100");
}
```

Вот для образца набросал в linqpad'е:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(@"<body><form><input name='asdf' value='12'></form></body>");

var element = document.QuerySelectorAll("input[name=asdf]").FirstOrDefault();
element.SetAttribute("value", "100");
//var newValue = element.GetAttribute("value");
//newVallue.Dump();
```